# How to pull a report of server name/id and kernel version of all servers in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, linux-kernel, cve

- I am using SSM to run `uname -srm` to identify the kernel versions of all the EC2 instances in a bunch of AWS accounts in my project.
- And I'm storing the results of SSM commands on S3
- Next I'm downloading the S3 contents and doing a grep on the results to see if there's a kernel 5.x being used

Is there a better way to automate this search? I just need a report of instance name/id, kernel vsersion.

I am doing this search to identify which servers are affected by the Dirty Pipe Linux kernel vuln (CVE-2022-0847).